# Remove Entries from Login Settings menu

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gdm

I wanted to know about removing the entries while logging in as they seem to be causing problems.

I only want to keep Gnome Classic and remove others.

Moreover, I seem to have messed up with the setup that points to Ubuntu entry so need to get it out of there.

[image: login screen options]

Edit 1:

As mentioned by PRATAP I have found the .desktop files for the corresponding sessions.

Also, instead of deleting the files, i have added the

```
.bak
```

suffix.
[image: xsessions]

Comment: seems you have manually deleted some sessions from files.. you can remove the other two entries also..

Comment: As far as I remember, I deleted the extension under /usr/share/gnome-shell/extentions path that had the name of Ubuntu Dash. Maybe that is causing an issue with selecting Ubuntu from the above menu. It goes in a login loop. I want to get rid of the entries now.

Comment: oh ok, can you access console by ctrl+alt+f2 or f3 or f4 then run commands in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands to keep only Gnome-Classic session and remove other sessions completely..

`sudo apt purge gnome-session`
`sudo apt purge ubuntu-session`
`sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean`
`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Still you will have Ubuntu and Ubuntu on wayland entries along with gnome-classic..
those things can be removed manually..

the sessions are stored in `/usr/share/xsessions/` and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/` but removing them manually is not suggested as some other dependent files will still be there in other folders.

i have manually deleted the files just to let you know the situation but it is not recommended..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

in the above pic there is no gear-icon meaning i have only one session..

Comment: Thank you. But I want to know the part of removing the entries manually.

Comment: sure i will update the answer..but since you have a login loop.. you need to purge ubuntu-session and then install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Thanks. I went through the config files for gdm under etc folder but did not find anything related to entries under that cog on login screen. Hence, turned to Ask Ubuntu for help.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks a lot. Moreover, I just printed the contents of those files using cat command. These are basically .desktop files. I guess I will have to uninstall whatever is mentioned in front of Exec in that file. Can you check once?

Comment: you can simply cut and save them in your home folder if you want them in future..

Comment: dont playwith the contents in exec line.. some are common to some sessions..

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. I will upvote your answer and not mark as accepted because I did not follow the uninstallation commands. I am unsure about them and feel that something might break. However, I followed the later part of your suggestion. Marking it as accepted will mislead others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91173/discussion-between-logan-and-pratap).